# Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?

Tags: html, browser, background-color

Why do certain random strings produce colors when entered as background colors in HTML?

For example, `bgcolor="chucknorris"` produces a **red background**:

```html
<body bgcolor="chucknorris"> test </body>
```

Conversely,  `bgcolor="chucknorr"` produces a **yellow background**:

```html
<body bgcolor="chucknorr"> test </body>
```

This holds true across various browsers and platforms. What’s going on here?

Comment: I had to (because how could I not) so I ran [an entire dictionary through a script and rendered it out as a table](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-dictionary-nfb5f) - and yes, `whippersnappers` is absolutely a valid color code.

Comment: This question was referenced in the podcast *[CoRecursive](https://corecursive.com/feed)*, in the [2022-01 episode](https://chtbl.com/track/7D91G/traffic.libsyn.com/secure/corecursive/072-Duct-Tape.mp3), at about 34 min 35 secs. Though the referenced answers and comments do ***not*** seem to be here (incl. in deleted answers). It *is* this question (unless there is another one with the same phrasing).

Comment: @mindplay.dk Currently fails with an endless stream of dependency errors.

Answer (score 8139, accepted):

It’s a holdover from the [Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_(web_browser)) days:

> Missing digits are treated as 0[...]. An incorrect digit is simply interpreted as 0. For example the values #F0F0F0, F0F0F0, F0F0F, #FxFxFx and FxFxFx are all the same.

It is from the blog post *[A little rant about Microsoft Internet Explorer's color parsing](http://scrappy-do.blogspot.com/2004/08/little-rant-about-microsoft-internet.html)* which covers it in great detail, including varying lengths of color values, etc.

If we apply the rules in turn from the blog post, we get the following:

1. Replace all nonvalid hexadecimal characters with 0’s:

   ```
   chucknorris becomes c00c0000000
   ```
2. Pad out to the next total number of characters divisible by 3 (11 → 12):

   ```
   c00c 0000 0000
   ```
3. Split into three equal groups, with each component representing the corresponding colour component of an RGB colour:

   ```
   RGB (c00c, 0000, 0000)
   ```
4. Truncate each of the arguments from the right down to two characters.

Which, finally, gives the following result:

```
RGB (c0, 00, 00) = #C00000 or RGB(192, 0, 0)
```

Here’s an example demonstrating the `bgcolor` attribute in action, to produce this “amazing” colour swatch:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="chucknorris" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">chuck norris</td>
    <td bgcolor="mrt"         cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center" style="color:#ffffff">Mr T</td>
    <td bgcolor="ninjaturtle" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center" style="color:#ffffff">ninjaturtle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="sick"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">sick</td>
    <td bgcolor="crap"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">crap</td>
    <td bgcolor="grass" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">grass</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This also answers the other part of the question: Why does `bgcolor="chucknorr"` produce a yellow colour? Well, if we apply the rules, the string is:

```
c00c00000 => c00 c00 000 => c0 c0 00 [RGB(192, 192, 0)]
```

Which gives a light yellow gold colour. As the string starts off as 9 characters, we keep the second ‘C’ this time around, hence it ends up in the final colour value.

I originally encountered this when someone pointed out that you could do `color="crap"` and, well, it comes out brown.

Comment: Fun fact - According to this logic then <body bgcolor="cabs"> test </body> would give you the color of a California Taxi Cab! The HQ of Netscape was in Mountain View, California!

Comment: Fun fact #2 - `Charmeleon`, `Ivysaur`, and `Squirtle` will produce red, green, and blue colors respectively.

Comment: Is the idea here that, if you're a programmer from some future society that uses 16 bits per color, present-day browsers will truncate them to the most significant 8 bits?

Comment: @warmCabin For proper colors at least I know it's possible to use more than 2 hex digits per color in modern browsers

Comment: There's one important rule missing: If first character of all components is "0", remove that character and then start truncacting to a lenght of two. All rules for this algorithm are listed here:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#colours

Answer (score 1211):

I'm sorry to disagree, but according to the rules for parsing a legacy color value [posted by Yuhong Bao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630675/282110), `chucknorris` *does not* equate to `#CC0000`, but rather to `#C00000`, a very similar but slightly different hue of red. I used the [Firefox ColorZilla add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorzilla/) to verify this.

The rules state:

- make the string a length that is a multiple of 3 by adding 0s: `chucknorris0`
- separate the string into three equal length strings: `chuc knor ris0`
- truncate each string to two characters: `ch kn ri`
- keep the hex values, and add 0's where necessary: `C0 00 00`

I was able to use these rules to correctly interpret the following strings:

- `LuckyCharms`
- `Luck`
- `LuckBeALady`
- `LuckBeALadyTonight`
- `GangnamStyle`

---

*The original answerers who said the color was `#CC0000` have since edited their answers to include the correction.*

Answer (score 557):

The reason is the browser can **not understand** it and try to somehow translate it to what it can understand and in this case into a **hexadecimal** value!...

`chucknorris` starts with `c` which is recognised character in hexadecimal, also it's converting all unrecognised characters into `0`!

So `chucknorris` in hexadecimal format becomes: `c00c00000000`, all other characters become `0` and `c` remains where they are...

Now they get divided by 3 for `RGB`(red, green, blue)... `R: c00c, G: 0000, B:0000`...

But we know valid hexadecimal for RGB is just 2 characters, means `R: c0, G: 00, B:00`

So the real result is:

```
bgcolor="#c00000";
```

I also added the steps in the image as a quick reference for you:

[image: Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a colour?]

Answer (score 475):

Most browsers will simply ignore any *non*-hexadecimal values in your color string, substituting non-hexadecimal digits with zeros.

`ChuCknorris` translates to `c00c0000000`.  At this point, the browser will divide the string into three equal sections, indicating *Red*, *Green* and *Blue* values: `c00c 0000 0000`.  Extra bits in each section will be ignored, which makes the final result `#c00000` which is a reddish color.

Note, this does *not* apply to CSS color parsing, which follow the CSS standard.

```html
<p><font color='chucknorris'>Redish</font></p>
<p><font color='#c00000'>Same as above</font></p>
<p><span style="color: chucknorris">Black</span></p>
```

Comment: `You might consider editing your answer, because the <font> element is hereby obsolete by HTML5.`

Answer (score 401):

The browser is trying to convert `chucknorris` into a hexadecimal color code because it’s not a valid value.

1. In `chucknorris`, everything except **`c`** is not a valid hexadecimal value.
2. So it gets converted to **`c00c00000000`**.
3. This is split into groups of 3, R G B (pad 0's at the end if not multiple of 3)
4. Of each group only two characters are picked as that is what's allowed.
5. It finally becomes **#c00000**, a shade of red.

This seems to be an issue primarily with **Internet  Explorer** and **Opera** (12) as both Chrome (31) and Firefox (26) just ignore this.

*P.S. The numbers in brackets are the browser versions I tested on.*

Similarly, [Rajnikanth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billa_(1980_film)) (Indian Chuck Noris) converse to a shade of black:

0a00 00a0 0000 => #0a0000

On a lighter note

> Chuck Norris doesn’t conform to web standards. Web standards conform
> to him. #BADA55

Comment: I have tested this on Firefox 26 and it works so I don't believe your reference is correct. Also from the following link http://scrappy-do.blogspot.com/2004/08/little-rant-about-microsoft-internet.html you will see that this was inherited from Netscape so it is not specific to Internet Explorer or Opera!

Answer (score 264):

The [WHATWG HTML specification has the exact algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#rules-for-parsing-a-legacy-colour-value) for parsing a legacy color value.

The code Netscape Classic used for parsing color strings is open source: *[netscape/lib/layout/layimage.c](https://github.com/zii/netscape/blob/master/lib/layout/layimage.c#L150)*.

For example, notice that each character is parsed as a hex digit and then is shifted into a 32-bit integer **without checking for overflow**. Only eight hex digits fit into a 32-bit integer, which is why only the last 8 characters are considered. After parsing the hex digits into 32-bit integers, they are then truncated into 8-bit integers by dividing them by 16 until they fit into 8-bit, which is why leading zeros are ignored.

This code does not exactly match what is defined in the spec, but the only difference there is a few lines of code. I think it is [these lines](https://github.com/zii/netscape/blob/master/lib/layout/layimage.c#L205) that were added (in Netscape 4):

```c
if (bytes_per_val > 4)
{
    bytes_per_val = 4;
}
```

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken. There doesn't seem to be a section with a headline of *"Rules for parsing a legacy colour value"* (or similar). Though there is a similar page anchor, "`legacy-extract-an-encoding`"

Comment: This is probably the correct link: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#colours

Answer (score 237):

- The browser will try to convert **chucknorris** into a hexadecimal value.
- Since `c` is the only valid hex character in **chucknorris**, the value turns into: `c00c00000000`(**0 for all values that were invalid**).
- The browser then divides the result into three groupds: `Red = c00c`, `Green = 0000`, `Blue = 0000`.
- Since valid hex values for HTML backgrounds only contain two digits for each color type (**r**, **g**, **b**), the last two digits are truncated from each group, leaving an RGB value of `c00000` which is a brick-reddish toned color.

Answer (score 67):

**`chucknorris`** starts with **`c`**, and the browser reads it into a hexadecimal value.

> Because A, B, C, D, E, and F are [characters in hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

The browser converts `chucknorris` to a hexadecimal value, `C00C00000000`.

Then the `C00C00000000` hexadecimal value is converted to **RGB** format (divided by 3):

> `C00C00000000` ⇒ `R:C00C, G:0000, B:0000`

The browser needs only two digits to indicate the colour:

> `R:C00C, G:0000, B:0000` ⇒ `R:C0, G:00, B:00` ⇒ `C00000`

Finally, show `bgcolor = C00000` in the web browser.

Here's an example demonstrating it:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="chucknorris" cellpadding="10" width="150" align="center">chucknorris</td>
    <td bgcolor="c00c00000000" cellpadding="10" width="150" align="center">c00c00000000</td>
    <td bgcolor="c00000" cellpadding="10" width="150" align="center">c00000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 53):

The [rules for parsing colors on legacy attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#rules-for-parsing-a-legacy-color-value) involves additional steps than those mentioned in existing answers. The truncate component to 2 digits part is described as:

1. Discard all characters except the last 8
2. Discard leading zeros one by one **as long as all components have a leading zero**
3. Discard all characters except the first 2

Some examples:

```
oooFoooFoooF
000F 000F 000F                <- replace, pad and chunk
0F 0F 0F                      <- leading zeros truncated
0F 0F 0F                      <- truncated to 2 characters from right

oooFooFFoFFF
000F 00FF 0FFF                <- replace, pad and chunk
00F 0FF FFF                   <- leading zeros truncated
00 0F FF                      <- truncated to 2 characters from right

ABCooooooABCooooooABCoooooo
ABC000000 ABC000000 ABC000000 <- replace, pad and chunk
BC000000 BC000000 BC000000    <- truncated to 8 characters from left
BC BC BC                      <- truncated to 2 characters from right

AoCooooooAoCooooooAoCoooooo
A0C000000 A0C000000 A0C000000 <- replace, pad and chunk
0C000000 0C000000 0C000000    <- truncated to 8 characters from left
C000000 C000000 C000000       <- leading zeros truncated
C0 C0 C0                      <- truncated to 2 characters from right
```

Below is a partial implementation of the algorithm. It does not handle errors or cases where the user enters a valid color.

```js
function parseColor(input) {
  // todo: return error if input is ""
  input = input.trim();
  // todo: return error if input is "transparent"
  // todo: return corresponding #rrggbb if input is a named color
  // todo: return #rrggbb if input matches #rgb
  // todo: replace unicode code points greater than U+FFFF with 00
  if (input.length > 128) {
    input = input.slice(0, 128);
  }
  if (input.charAt(0) === "#") {
    input = input.slice(1);
  }
  input = input.replace(/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/g, "0");
  while (input.length === 0 || input.length % 3 > 0) {
    input += "0";
  }
  var r = input.slice(0, input.length / 3);
  var g = input.slice(input.length / 3, input.length * 2 / 3);
  var b = input.slice(input.length * 2 / 3);
  if (r.length > 8) {
    r = r.slice(-8);
    g = g.slice(-8);
    b = b.slice(-8);
  }
  while (r.length > 2 && r.charAt(0) === "0" && g.charAt(0) === "0" && b.charAt(0) === "0") {
    r = r.slice(1);
    g = g.slice(1);
    b = b.slice(1);
  }
  if (r.length > 2) {
    r = r.slice(0, 2);
    g = g.slice(0, 2);
    b = b.slice(0, 2);
  }
  return "#" + r.padStart(2, "0") + g.padStart(2, "0") + b.padStart(2, "0");
}

$(function() {
  $("#input").on("change", function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var color = parseColor(input);
    var $cells = $("#result tbody td");
    $cells.eq(0).attr("bgcolor", input);
    $cells.eq(1).attr("bgcolor", color);

    var color1 = $cells.eq(0).css("background-color");
    var color2 = $cells.eq(1).css("background-color");
    $cells.eq(2).empty().append("bgcolor: " + input, "<br>", "getComputedStyle: " + color1);
    $cells.eq(3).empty().append("bgcolor: " + color, "<br>", "getComputedStyle: " + color2);
  });
});
```

```css
body { font: medium monospace; }
input { width: 20em; }
table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input id="input" placeholder="Enter color e.g. chucknorris"></p>
<table id="result">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Left Color</th>
      <th>Right Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```