# Translate HTML colors to HSV

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of color names:

```
bunchofcolornames = [
            "aliceblue",
            "antiquewhite",
            "aqua",
            "cyan"] #this list is actually much longer...
```

For my matplotlib plots, I want to select those, which appear rather dark on a white background. For this I'd like to get the shade value in the HSV representation of that color name. How to do this best?

Comment: In "hue, saturation, value" there isn't a shade. Do you mean you want the value?

Comment: I hope you plan on implementing it properly and including [legacy netscape behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)...

Comment: Yes. I messed that up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [color](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colour) package which supports converting color names to HSL.

Comment: Although the `color` package is indeed exactly what the OP needs, you could have provided a short sample showing how that library provides exactly that translation. As it stands, your answer could have been a comment, as it contains nothing more than a link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python, but I can answer the language-agnostic part of this:

The value part of RGB to HSV is the simplest part; it's the maximum of the R, G and B component divided by 255.0. (The HSL and HSI representations are slightly different with HSL averaging the largest and smallest of the three RGB components and HSI averaging all three).

For predicting contrast, you might be better off using *luma*, which for the sRGB colourspace is `R ÷ 255.0 × 0.21 + G ÷ 255.0 × 0.72 + B ÷ 255.0 × 0.07`. For other colourspaces it's slightly different (e.g with NTSC televisions it's `R ÷ 255.0 × 0.3 + G ÷ 255.0 × 0.59 + B ÷ 255.0 × 0.11`), but for guessing whether to pair with black or white, just sticking with sRGB should give reasonable results.