# HTML White Color Font Shows Yellow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to edit an HTML page's color fonts in a table.  I've been asked to give it a red background and white font.  Problem is, when I do the white, it just shows up as yellow on the page.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong, honestly I'm not terribly great at this, we just have no one else.

Here's the table (only worrying about the first cell right now)

```
<table border="3">
<tr>
<th><td bgcolor="#B22222;"><font color="#FFFFFF;" size="+1">Queue</font></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why are you using HTML from the '90's?

Comment: I would look into something called css.

Comment: haha, i wanted to say the same thing. Only a little more constructively

Comment: it's just how it was given to me is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon is playing tricks on you. Take it out.

```
<font color="#FFFFFF" size="+1">Queue</font>
```

Now use CSS or something. [CSS doesn’t think Chuck Norris is a colour.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

```
<h2>Queue</h2>
```

```css
h2 {
    background-color: #b22222;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because it's white on red background,and possibly low quality monitor. The high contrast, horribly color scheme is create issue for you.
Thats my guess anyways.