# My jQuery doesn't change the fontcolor with the .css() function

Tags: jquery, css

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('h3').hover(function() {
          $('h3').css({"color","#OOFFFF"});
      });
  });
  </script>
```

This is my code, placed at the end of my HTML document, before the end of `<body>`. I'm trying to make my `h3` tag change its color to a light blue when I hover over it. This isn't working in my HTML:

```
<h3 class="masthead-brand">sunil singh</h3>
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You are missing a http: in <script src> tag. It should be <script src=" h t t p : //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @skjindal93: nope, this is perfectly fine. This way the browser calls `http://ajax...` if you are on a http connection, and `https://ajax...` if you are on a https website :) Rather smart solution really. And one provided by jQuery itself ;)

Comment: But what if I run it locally on the system? It will call with file:// extension which will not work.

Comment: @skjindal93: That is right, the URL only works when the page is fetched using the `http:` or `https:` protocol. It's not intended for use in pages that you view locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, missing `:`. You are confusing the `method('prop', 'value')` with `method({ prop: 'value' })` syntax. Also, you're using an O ("Oh") instead of a 0 (zero). The "Oh" is not a hex value.

```
  $('h3').hover(function() {
      // `this` here refers to the hovered element 
      $(this).css({"color": "#00FFFF"});
  });
```

Comment: Also, as mentioned by @Guffa, using letters in color codes can cause [unexpected results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color).

Comment: Worthy a note: It might be better to add a class, eg `.hovermode`, and give that the new font color. Style should remain in stylesheets as much as possible. What if you want this effect on more locations? or want it another color?

Comment: Thank you! This and @Guffa's answer did it for me. I appreciate the assistance, as I am just starting out with jQuery.

Comment: Not 100% sure (someone might want to perf), but I believe that `.css('color','#0FF')` is faster than `.css({color:'#0FF'})` due to the fact it doesnt need to literate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the code. You have a comma instead of a colon in the object literal.

There is an error in your color code. You have two O characters instead of two zero digits.

This:

```
$('h3').css({"color","#OOFFFF"});
```

should be:

```
$('h3').css({"color":"#00FFFF"});
```

---

Side note: The color `#00FFFF` is not light blue, it's cyan.

Another side note: You can use CSS for hover effects, then the effect also goes away when you no longer hover over the element. Example (goes in the `head` element):

```
<style>
h3:hover { color: #00FFFF; }
</style>
```

Comment: oh, the oh instead of zero, very sharp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('h3').hover(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "red");   
      });
  });
```

Added a `comma` or `,` instead of a `colon` or `:` in `css("color", "red")`

I made it `red` as an example, change it for your needs :)

Note: It is better to use a class in your function unless you want all `h3` to change color on hovering

Comment: where did masthead-brand come from?

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend sticking to `#0FF` as it´s a tad faster :) (not really noticable, but the devil is in the details)

Comment: @scunliffe `<h3 class="masthead-brand">sunil singh</h3>` I suppose you could use h3 as well

Comment: If you're gonna add an answer which has been added 3 other times, at least make sure ou are conform... THe TS uses h3, not a class. Dont change those things as it might confuse people. If you want to add a class (which _might_ be better), add  that as a note

Comment: I believe, I was one of the first one to post the answer but I will add your notes. Please check when other answers were posted