# CSS: a weird color issue?

Tags: html, css, background-color

If I try to apply this color to a HTML element:

```
background-color: #COFFEE; /* Should work, has 6 characters */
```

The color gets ignored and white (#FFF) is shown instead.

If I do:

```
background-color: #C0FFEE;
```

The color changes to something like green.

And:

```
background-color: #CFE;
```

Is probably the same color. I tested this in FF only.

Comment: Why should the first one work? These are hexadecimal color codes for a reason ---> 0-9 + A-F

Comment: COFFEE isn't valid hexadecimal. C0FFEE is.

Comment: How could any user upvote this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: Write 100 times: `0 != O`

Comment: Another reason why Lucida Console is a terrible programmer's font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hex color code consists of digits `0` to `9` and letters `A` to `F`, representing `10` to `15` in decimal mode.

So `O` is not a valid hex value, but `0` is.

So `#COFFEE;` won't work, but `#C0FFEE;` will.

If you want to use named colors, refer to: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/ and have a look at section 4.3. `Extended color keywords`

E.g. [Choclate](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#chocolate) which is `#d2691e` in hex and `210,105,30` in RGB.

Answer (score 1):

`COFFEE` is not a valid [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number. The sixteen hex digits are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E and F.

`C0FFEE`, on the other hand, is.

C0<sub>16</sub> = 192<sub>10</sub>, 192/255 = 75% red
FF<sub>16</sub> = 255<sub>10</sub>, 255/255 = 100% green
EE<sub>16</sub> = 238<sub>10</sub>, 238/255 = 93% blue

`CFE` means the same as `CCFFEE`, which is indeed very similar.

CC<sub>16</sub> = 204<sub>10</sub>, 192/255 = 80% red
FF<sub>16</sub> = 255<sub>10</sub>, 255/255 = 100% green
EE<sub>16</sub> = 238<sub>10</sub>, 238/255 = 93% blue

If you were looking for predefined names, you'll find them [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4) plus [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color).

Answer (score 0):

The color #COFFEE doesn't exist. You need to write the color code in hexadecimal after the hashtag (#), it ranges from 0 to 9 and A to F. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

The color #C0FFEE (with a zero) works, but not #COFFEE (with an O).

The color #CFE is not equivalent to #C0FFEE, but to #CCFFEE.

Answer (score 0):

> `#COFFEE`

The letter O is not a valid hex value. As such, the browser will attempt to do something to accomdoate the error. That is likely going to be unpredictable.

> `#C0FFEE`

That is a valid hex color.

> `#CFE;`

Also a valid hex color in that it is shorthand for `#ccffee`

> `coffee`

Not a valid HTML color name. However, if you are looking for a color that looks like coffee, and want to use a name value, you could try `chocolate` which is a valid color name.