# JavaScript for move upload file

Tags: javascript, php

I just try move upload file when the form controlled by JavaScript.
Is possible for move upload file use JavaScript?
If it possible, what script for do that?

Comment: It could be up or down @KirillPisarev ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Why does HTML think...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: the file move to folder on server. it's used for server only. any idea? I'm newby and still learning. if that possible, I wanna try do that.

Comment: @KirillPisarev, what mean move right or left or up or down? sorry I'm not understand.

Answer (score 0):

How can you move uploaded file, which is on server with Javascript, which runs on client's machine? No, you can't do that.

Comment: thanks @MilanG. I just used on the server.. I'm newby and still learning. if that possible, I wanna try do that :)

Comment: I think that's Ok. I don't understand those guys that are giving negative votes or put some "funny" comments - when you are beginner it's normal to ask "silly" questions. As someone said, there are no stupid questions, just stupid answers. :)