# Why bgcolor="orrange" gives a blue color?

Tags: html, css

I was writing some HTML for my new project and I wanted the background to be of 'orange' color. By mistake, I wrote

```
<body bgcolor="orrange">content</body>
```

I saw that the background was of 'blue' color. Then I found an error in the spelling of 'orange'. But why did 'blue' color appear when I wrote 'orrange'?

Comment: Please, provide whole html file(Doctype)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color?rq=1. Its because **orrange** becomes `#00a0e0` (see the explanation in that answer).

Comment: It's even more fun with colors like `copper`, which don't even have to be misspelled, but which are not recognised by all browsers.