# Where do the CSS color names come from?

Tags: css, colors

I was looking for color options for a theme I was working on and there was a bunch of odd names for regular colors. Some of the colors were FireBrick for red, Gainsboro for light grey, NavajoWhite for a subtle yellow color which makes no sense because it is not at all white. Does anyone know why these names exist?

Comment: There are many shades of red; if FireBrick was called red, what would you call all the other reds? They do differ. If you just want the ROYGBIV colors, use them.

Comment: Because Chuck Norris said so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmStJQzclHc

Comment: All modern browsers support the following 140 color names (click on a color name, or a hex value, to view the color as the background-color along with different text colors). These names exists because, we can call them 'names' and are easily understandable.

You may check **[HTML Color Names][1]**


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/tomato-versus-ff6347-the-tragicomic-history-of-css-color-names/

Comment: [Because. I. Like. Colours](http://colours.neilorangepeel.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those extended color names are [imported from SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords), which itself takes from the X11 color system. See [section 4.3 of css3-color](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color).

If you're asking how those names were chosen to begin with, that's not something anyone but those who originally named the colors can answer (although, according to [this mailing list reference](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Mar/0272.html) from Wikipedia, one of the comments on your question is somewhat on point re: Crayola colors).