# What is the CSS colour name: "background"?

Tags: css, colors, background

`background` is a valid colour in CSS. It differs per browser; it's a shade of purple in chromium. I can't find any information on it and was wondering why it exists and what it is.

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: background;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting.  For me, it shows as a dark red (#800000) in IE11 and firefox, but a bluish color (#6363CE) in Chrome.

Comment: At first, I thought that this question could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color, but it isn't, because the letters BAC are absent from these hex codes.

Comment: This is a duplicate !! If you look to the right, you will see "Related".

Comment: @monstro as the comment above says (and my answer makes clear by giving the actual reason), it's *not* a duplicate of that linked question. If `background` was being interpreted the same way as `chucknorris` it would: 1. be consistent between browsers; and 2. be `#ba000d`, not `#800000` or `#6363CE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to one of the [CSS2 system colours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#System_Colors), now [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css2-system).

Note that you get the same result with `Background`, as it's listed in that documentation; CSS is case insensitive, I think they're just listed in `CamelCase` to make the word boundaries clearer.

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: Background;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```