# Javascript strings as hex color codes

Tags: javascript, hex, background-color

Yesterday, I wanted to make a hex color previewer because I google searched the hex values and didn't get a color, instead I got Japanese sites & obscure cooking products. So I made the [previewer](https://pixelxii.github.io/Utilities/hex/), in simple JS  and HTML. This morning, I was experimenting with the hex values and found that random words are valid as a hex value. 'Firetruck' is a nice yellow. I asked one of my teachers about it and he wondered if JS was interpreting 'firetruck' as a hexadecimal value. I set up an alert, to display the input of the user, and the background color of the document. Javascript is *not* switching to hex, but  the word 'firetruck' in hex is yellow.

What is going on???

Comment: As 'hex' is for 'hexadecimal', ideally it should not have values *more than* **F**. And [this](https://www.w3schools.com/Colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp) does not show `firetruck` yellowish or so. Maybe you can share the code behind your picker.

Comment: Related if not a dupe: [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318911)

Comment: It is an exact duplicate, thank you.