# Colors in web with ";"

Tags: html, colors

Why if I set up background something as "red" like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="red">example</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

I get a red cell. But if attribute will be "bgcolor="red;" I get... GREEN cell!
Also, it works with blue and blue; , green and green;

What is `<color>;` in html? Is this documentated?

Comment: I'd say this is the same as [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color), but I'm not sure if the answer to that addresses the semicolon part.

Comment: also as a note do not use bgcolor use background-color

Comment: @BoltClock the semicolon is inside the quotes rather than outside. Maybe that's why?

Comment: @Andrew Fan: Yeah, I know. It seems that ; just becomes 0 - I forgot that the algorithm just zeroes out all ASCII characters that aren't hex.

Comment: @Julian Silvestri bUgcolor a lot of more funny, I think.