# Get the average color of an arbitrary text character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, character

I'm trying to get the average color (rgba) of a single arbitrary character in Javascript.  I'm aware this may produce different results on different setups; that's fine and expected behavior.  How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean, "the average colour of a character"?

Comment: I mean literally "what's the average color of the pixels that make up the x-y dimensions that the character takes up"

Answer (score -2):

You might be thinking about how browsers interpret a string value of the `bgColor` property like a color by splitting the string into three hex values. Which is why `element.bgColor = "chucknorris"` changes the element's background colour to RGB(192, 0, 0).

See the below answer for more examples and a description of why it happens.

[Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: is there something worthy of a downvote in my answer?

Comment: I am not thinking of this.  I mean literally how do I figure out the average color of an arbitrary character chosen at random, like "A" or ""

Comment: no need for a downvote though! You could have phrased your question a bit better. You'll need to choose a font to inspect in order to get the average colour. Characters are not stored as 'pixel-maps' inside JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you!  Though I can see why you would think that, I would assume the same :)  I can give you a second and then remove it later to prove it if you like lol

Comment: Could it be drawn and measured in a canvas?