# Why doesn't the color fall back to black?

Tags: html, css

I'm maintaining an old website and had the opportunity to touch old age HTML. So I encountered a strange behavior of the `color` attribute.

In the following source code, both texts are red:

```css
p {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>

  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <font color="#ff0000">
      hello, world!
    </font>
    <p>
      hello, world!
    </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

The color code consists of hexadecimal numbers and is (basically) 6 characters. However, the behavior of the `color` attribute and the `color` property differ when entering a color code of 6 characters or more.

```css
p {
  color: #ff0000abc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <font color="#ff0000abc">
    hello, world!
  </font>

  <p>
    hello, world!
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Why is this and how the `color` attribute works here? I still have to use the `color` attribute, so I need to know this rule.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333464/12983620), I thought that the color code `#ff00c0` was used, but according to inspect actually used color using [firefox's dropper tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Eyedropper), actually `#ff00ab` was using.

Comment: `#ff0000abc;` is not a valid color so it takes its first parent color with a valid color

Comment: @AlonEitan However, it works with the `color` attribute. I am asking why it works and the for calculated values.

Comment: @AlonEitan it's not about the CSS color here but the attribute color

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just got it now. Do you know why it's being converted to a valid HEX color when it's in the attribute, but not when it comes from the style?

Comment: @AlonEitan the CSS syntax is more strict and accept only a specifc format white attribute can accept almost anything and the browser will try to convert to something valid. Don't know the reason behind this but I know it's like that. It's like doing `width="205defd"`  and the browser will consider the width to be `205px`. You cannot do this with CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the answer you linked we will have the following steps:

```
#ff0000abc ---> # ff0 000 abc ---> # ff 00 ab ---> #ff00ab
```

And not `#ff00c0`

Without considering the `#` You have 9 characters (divisible by 3) so you won't add any more. You group them into 3 and you cut the extra ones in each group to keep only 2.

Comment: I misunderstood that the second part of the procedure requires zero padding to 12 characters.

Comment: @hyp-ho I am trying to find where it's defined in the Spec

Comment: I have found these in the [latest WHATWG specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#rules-for-parsing-a-legacy-colour-value), but I haven't yet found it in the W3C specifications at the time.

Comment: @hyp-ho this is it. You won't find something in the W3C Spec because this is related to the HTML world and not the CSS one even if later it will get used in the cascade but this is a different story.