# Why is #ff7f7f7f pink?

Tags: html

Shouldn't it be some sort of grey? But both FireFox and Chrome shows it like pink. When I entered that value in Paint.NET it looked grey. Why does `#ff7f7f7f` look pink on web browsers?

[image]

[image]

```html
<html><body>
<h1 style="background: #ff7f7f7f">Why does #ff7f7f7f look like this?</h1>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Odd as it sounds, I believe your question is answered here: [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: Is it showing as a pink color anywhere else? Is this even programming related?

Comment: You've mixed up the order with alpha channel.  It's not ARGB, it's RGBA.

Comment: @IMSoP No, I don't think that answers this. That is about ignoring invalid characters in the colour hexadecimal string, but this was about the order of colour components.

Comment: @DamnVegetables The answers also discuss how colours which aren't multiples of 3 in length are handled; I wasn't aware that some browsers now handle 4 and 8 character strings as RGBA instead of applying that algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#ff7f7f7f` corresponding to `#rrggbbaa` notation which is RED-GREEN-BLUE-ALPHA values, two hex characters for each value. The color is the pink you are getting.

I guess copying into `Paint.NET` just trims the first two characters because it expecting only `#rrggbb` notation, trimming it into `#7f7f7f` which is gray. (But i'm not familier how `Paint.NET` works :) )

Comment: Indeed, `ff7f7f` is a dark pink, but with `7f` opacity it becomes lighter.

Comment: Yeah, the data source used ARGB hexadeximal format like #AARRGGBB, and somehow I just assumed that HTML/CSS would also  use ARGB format. After some web research, it seems they use RGBA. I tried to mark this as the answer, but it seems I have to wait.

Comment: I might be wrong, but my impression from the "chucknorris" question linked above is that hex colours are always interpreted as RGB, not RGBA.

Comment: @IMSoP some browser's versions supports it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa

Comment: @SomoKRoceS Ah, I didn't know that; I guess the linked question predates that, which is why the answers talk about finding the nearest multiple of three. I wonder if chucknorris has changed colour as a result. :)

Comment: @IMSoP that's an interesting question :P I'm not sure if the default notation is #rrggbb or #rrggbbaa (I think it's still #rrggbb and only if the value is 8 characters long it is considered as #rrggbbaa but I didn't verified it).

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the element with the browser's dev tools you can check the computed style and you'll see it's parsed as an rgba color (`rgba(255, 127, 127, 0.498)`)

EDIT: note that the color picker software you are using is not picking the color of the div but the color of the screen pixel (which is some pink color with ~0.5 alpha with white behind, that's why you get that weird FFBFBF color there)

Comment: You are right about the developer tools. Browsers seem to use RGBA, not ARGB.