# Why is background-color: background; purple on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Yesterday I found out that Chrome take `background` as a valid css color.

So I've instantly searched for some answers, but couldn't find any. Is there any explanation to why `background` is a valid css color (at least on chrome), and why it is purple?

[image: example]

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: Seem like it does, thanks!