# Transparent <font color> becomes red

Tags: html, css

This html shows a red text in Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<font color="rgba(0,0,0,0)">foobar</font>
```

One would expect transparent font. Is this a browser-bug?

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated, you should not use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing HTML and CSS. The `color` attribute of the `font` element only takes an hex value, such as `#000000`  which doesn't support transparency. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font#attr-color). `rgba(0,0,0,0)` is CSS syntax and can't be used there.

Generally you shouldn't be using the `font` element anyway.

Comment: As for why the `color` is interpreted as red, I expect the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color will explain it.

Comment: You are right - this explains why.