# Why is "field" a valid color name in CSS?

Tags: html, css, colors

I have created a function `isColor` that relies on `CSS.supports` to determine whether some text is an HTML color or not. This works perfect for color names like `red` and hex colors like `#3883fa`. However, for the text `field`, the function `CSS.supports('color', 'field')` returns `true` too. The name `field` is not mentioned in the list with [CSS color names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/named-color), and I would expect `CSS.supports` to return `false` in this case.

Why is this the case? Are there other cases like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: @Cybertine - This is about CSS colors, not HTML colors - `CSS.supports('color', 'chucknorris')` returns false.

Comment: I mean, is it the same concept?

Comment: Thanks Cybertine, it looks like the `chucknorris` case is a different category of false positives, but like @Alohci explains in an answer, the cause of "field" being defined as a number is different. Both are categories that are "false positives", and I'll need to take care of both to determine whether something is a valid color not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a system color meaning the background color of an input field, as defined at [Field](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#valdef-color-field) in the latest draft of [CSS Color Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#css-system-colors).

---

<sub>As noted in the question comments, CSS.supports tests for CSS colors, which doesn't apply the "error correction" algorithm used by colors in HTML attributes. For that, practically every string of characters gets interpreted as a color when used in an HTML attribute that expects a color value.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, and also answers the question whether there are more names like this. A similar issue with a different cause is [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color), all in all I can now see how to come up with a more reliable `isColor` function.